# find string and stored the replaced string in other file shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I want to find a string say 'foo' in a file sat '1.txt' using shell script and replace 'foo' with 'bar' and store the output into other file say '2.txt' without any modification in 1.txt.

so '1.txt' would contain 'foo' itself but '2.txt' will now have all the contents of '1.txt' with 'foo' replaced by 'bar'

I am using this command in bash

```
sed -i "s/foo/bar/g" "1.txt" > 2.txt
```

but its not working.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `-i` option as it stands for in-place operation.

```
-i[SUFFIX], --in-place[=SUFFIX]

      edit files in place (makes backup if extension supplied)
```

*(sed(1) man page)*

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `-i` switch, or provide a backup extension (`-i.bak`), so the modified file will be `1.txt` and `1.txt.bak` the original backup.
You don't need quotes on `"1.txt"`, unless the filename contains spaces.

```
sed "s/foo/bar/g" 1.txt > 2.txt
```

or

```
sed  -i.bak "s/foo/bar/g" 1.txt
```

---

Take a look at [sed manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.txt)